# Processing (the Java visualization language): spinning rectangle leaving odd fading trail effect with rectMode(CENTER) but not rectMode(CORNER)

Tags: java, processing

I am practicing with objects leaving fading trail effects as they move. At the moment I am making a rectangle rotate clockwise in the middle of the canvas and drawing a low-opacity rectangle over the canvas each frame, yielding a nice fading trail.

**The problem:** the fading trail only fully fades when I use rectMode(CORNER). [I should mention that not mentioning rectMode defaults to CORNER.] This is undesirable, as the rectangle pivots about a corner, instead of its center.
I would prefer to use rectMode(CENTER), but the motion trail doesn't fully fade with this command. Instead, the trails build to 3/4 of a circle of solid, fully opaque color.

I attempted to include a screenshot of the odd 3/4 motion trail circle, but am being told that I lack the necessary reputation.

This is so strange that it seems like a bug.
Any ideas?

```
int shapeSize = 150;
float q = 0;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  smooth();
  noStroke();
  background(0);
}

void draw() {

  noStroke();
  fill( 0, 15);  //builds up low-opacity layers over object
  rect(0, 0, width, height);

  //pushMatrix();
  rectMode(CENTER);  //TOGGLE ON AND OFF TO SEE THE ISSUE
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  rotate(q);
  noStroke();
  fill(255,255);
  rect(0,0, shapeSize,shapeSize);
  q += 0.02;
  //popMatrix();  //Tried toggling push and popMatrix -- no luck
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would always be hesitant of accusing a language of having bugs :) Try the following code and I think you will see why this behavior occurs. (It's the same as yours, only I changed the color of the translucent rectangle). If you'd like more explanation, leave a comment and I'd be happy to oblige.

```java
int shapeSize = 150;
float q = 0;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  smooth();
  noStroke();
  background(0);
}

void draw() {

  noStroke();
  fill( 100, 15);  //builds up low-opacity layers over object
  rect(0, 0, width, height);

  //pushMatrix();
  rectMode(CENTER);  //TOGGLE ON AND OFF TO SEE THE ISSUE
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  rotate(q);
  noStroke();
  fill(255,255);
  rect(0,0, shapeSize,shapeSize);
  q += 0.02;
  //popMatrix();  //Tried toggling push and popMatrix -- no luck
}
```

Comment: Ahh many thanks Kevin!! Yes, I was certainly a bit rash in my bug accusations. Simply moving the translucent rectangle's code to after the spinning rectangle was sufficient. Again, thank you!

Comment: I think technically it should be before your spinning rectangle, but after the translation. If it's after, then the spinner is never really at full strength (doesn't matter, I'm just saying this for interest). Thanks for a fun problem :)